# Technical question in Vandermonde determinat proof

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, determinant

I can follow the proof given [in](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) (2nd proof, or the induction proof),  until the sentence: *"From the Expansion Theorem for Determinants‎, we can see that the coefficient of $x_k$ is:"*.

I don't understand why it is only needed the determinant of the cofactor of $x_k$, since the calculation of a determinant involves taking one row and the multiplication of the cofactors in the chosen row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been shown that the determinant is something like:

$$V_{k+1}(x) = f(x) = C(x-a_2)(x-a_3)\ldots(x-a_k)(x-a_{k+1})$$

Note that if you would expand this it would be of the form:

$$f(x) = Cx^k + B_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\ldots$$

Now consider the expansion theorem for the first row:

$$V_{k+1}(x) = \begin{vmatrix}
a_2^{k-1} & \cdots & a_2^2 & a_2 & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{k+1}^{k-1} & \cdots & a_{k+1}^2 & a_{k+1} & 1
\end{vmatrix}x^k +B_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\ldots$$

Where $B_{i}$ is some constant.

Comment: So the $B$'s are already in the $f(x)$ polynomial, right?

Comment: @user2820579 If you would expand it, yes. I've called the coefficients of the $x^i:$ $B_i$.

Comment: Super! Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

It's talking about how you work out determinants you can "expand" them into a sum of 2x2 determinants

It's what I did here ( [Vandermonde determinant by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525334/vandermonde-determinant-by-induction) ) 2 years ago.

Comment: I understand your derivation and also checked it, thanks for the feedback. I don't understand the line that I wrote in ".." in the second proof given in the webàge I posted. I corrected the question.

Comment: @user2820579 it's literally in that question