# Curious self-similarity hiding in special case of Sherman-Morrison inversion. What does it imply?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, similar-matrices

Trying to help [deriving a special case of Sherman Morrison formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472125/derivation-of-the-forumal-i-cdt-1-i-fraccdt1-dtc/3472230?noredirect=1#comment7138208_3472230), I found something peculiar.

I made the ansatz $$(I+cd^T)^{-1} = I + A$$

Which lead me to two different ways to build identity matrix: $$(I+A)(I+cd^T) = (I+cd^T)(I+A)$$

$$I+cd^T+A+Acd^T = I + A + cd^T + cd^TA$$

$$Acd^T = cd^TA$$

Now since $cd^T$ is a rank 1 outer product, it cannot have an inverse, but $A$ might:

$$cd^T = A^{-1}(cd^T)A$$

$$A(cd^T)A^{-1} = cd^T$$

In other words the rank-1 update $cd^T$ is *similar to itself* under $A$ transformation.

What does this lead to? Is it common to have this relationship between matrices, or is it something special?

Comment: Since $A$ is proportional to $cd^T$ in also commutes with it.

Comment: @user721481 ah yep, but if it is proportional to it then $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist :/ yeah not very interesting then.