# Determinant of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have the following problem:

> Let $(a_{1},\dots,a_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a vector and let the matrix
> (Vandermonde) \begin{equation*}
>          V = 
>          \begin{pmatrix}
>              1&a_{1}&a_{1}^{2}&\dots&a_{1}^{n-2}&a_{1}^{n-1}\\
>              1&a_{2}&a_{2}^{2}&\dots&a_{2}^{n-2}&a_{2}^{n-1}\\
>              \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
>              1&a_{n}&a_{n}^{2}&\dots&a_{n}^{n-2}&a_{n}^{n-1}
> >         \end{pmatrix} \end{equation*} Prove that \begin{equation*}
>          \text{det}(V) = \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n}(a_{j}-a_{i}). \end{equation*}

---

What I have tried is, by induction:
\begin{equation*}
            V_{2} =
            \begin{pmatrix}
                1&a_{1}\\
                1&a_{2}
            \end{pmatrix}
            \Rightarrow
            \text{det}(V_{2}) = a_{2} - a_{1},
\end{equation*}
Suppose it is true for $ n $. Let's try to test it for $ n + 1 $, let
\begin{equation*}
            V_{n+1} = 
            \begin{pmatrix}
                1&a_{1}&a_{1}^{2}&\dots&a_{1}^{n-2}&a_{1}^{n-1}&a_{1}^{n}\\
                1&a_{2}&a_{2}^{2}&\dots&a_{2}^{n-2}&a_{2}^{n-1}&a_{2}^{n}\\
                \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
                1&a_{n}&a_{n}^{2}&\dots&a_{n}^{n-2}&a_{n}^{n-1}&a_{n}^{n}\\
                1&a_{n+1}&a_{n+1}^{2}&\dots&a_{n+1}^{n-2}&a_{n+1}^{n-1}&a_{n+1}^{n}
            \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
an indication is to use appropriate determinant properties and row operations.

Comment: How about using cofactor etension?

Comment: This has been asked here before, and full inductive proofs have been given. Did you try searching?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525334/vandermonde-determinant-by-induction for some sample proofs.